# Custom icon with fontello not working React Native

Tags: react-native, icons, fontello, icomoon

Hi I'm trying to implement custom icons following similar tutorials from online but keep running into the same problem with different approaches. First I uploaded the svg to the fontello service. Then I put the .ttf file into my assets/fonts folder. Then I placed the config.json file in my src base folder. Finally, I linked them and even checked build phase settings to make sure its there in xcode. However, the icon doesn't show up with the following code and it shows up instead a question mark inside a white box.What should i be doing?

```
import { createIconSetFromFontello } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import fontelloConfig from '../config.json';
const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig);
...
 render(){
    <Icon name="Icon_X" size={80} color="#000"/>
 }
```